# How to get the TextView and Button list from a view

Tags: android, textview, onclicklistener, buttonclick

First, sorry for my English and my knowledge, I'm a french Android Studio beginner.

I've a view in a fragment named root : `View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_about, container, false);` defined in onCreateView. In this view, I've four buttons and four textview, each textview being assigned to a button. And my idea is to hide and show the textview when the user click the assigned button.

So I've defined an onClickListener for each button, and the parameter of this Listener is "this" : `mAboutPartButton1.setOnClickListener(this);`. So I suppose that "this" means the current view.

I then set the onClick void whith a View parameter, and I would like get the Textview list present in the view to hide and show the appropriated Textview.

The problem is that I don't know how can I get this list of Textviews.

Thank you for all your answers !

Comment: Use view.getId inside switch case. 
Case R.id.text1 :  do stuff
Case R.id.text2: do stuff

Comment: Thank you so much I am going to try it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.text1:
                    // do your stuff
                    break;

                case R.id.text2:

                    //do your stuff
                    break;
            }
```

Comment: Yes, thank you so much, this part is working, but I have a new problem just then, and I don't know how to resolve it, so I don't know if I can post it here, or I have to make a new topic.

Comment: Accept this answer and raise a new problem topic. Otherwise, people might get confuse. which one to answer.

Comment: Your welcome. Post your new query. Ready to help you there